# How to Print and Save a .csv list from Wikipedia

Tags: export-to-csv

I'm trying to print and save (as a .csv) a list from Wikipedia. I am not sure where I am going wrong with my code. Any suggestions?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Game_of_Thrones_episodes")
result

page = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
soup 

table = soup.find("table", {"class" : "wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable"})
table

    f = open('output.csv', 'w')
    for row in table.findAll("th"):
        cells = row.findAll("td")
        if len(cells) == 7:

            No_overall = cells[0].find(text = True)

            No_in_season = cells[1].find(text = True)

            Title = cells[2].find(text = True)

            Directed_by = cells[3].find(text = True)

            Written_by = cells[4].find(text = True)

            Original_air_date = cells[5].find(text = True).replace(',','')

            US_viewers = cells[6].find(text = True).replace('.','')

            line = No_overall  + "," + No_in_season + "," + Title + "," +          
    Directed_by +"," + Written_by + "," + Original_air_date + "," +      
    US_viewers + "\n"

            print(line)

            f.write(write_to_file)
```

Comment: What is going wrong? what part of the code is not working as expected

Comment: My professor said len(cells) does not = 7 for this table and therefore I am missing all the other data. Can I write the code as if len(cells) ==(rows,columns)? Would that give me the whole data table?

Answer (score 0):

The line  `for row in table.findAll("th"):` is not correct.  `tr` is a row of cells in the table. You cann't get an `td` information from `findAll("th")`

Change it to `for row in table.findAll("tr"):` and your code will work

Check a simple HTML table with 2 header cells and two data cells:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit**:
taking one row output as example:

```
<tr class="vevent" style="text-align:center;background:inherit">
<th id="ep9" scope="row" style="text-align:center">9</th>
<td>9</td>
<td class="summary" style="text-align:left">"<a href="/wiki/Baelor" title="Baelor">Baelor</a>"</td>
<td><a href="/wiki/Alan_Taylor_(director)" title="Alan Taylor (director)">Alan Taylor</a></td>
<td>David Benioff &amp; D. B. Weiss</td>
<td>June 12, 2011<span style="display:none"> (<span class="bday dtstart published updated">2011-06-12</span>)</span></td>
<td>2.66<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-26"><a href="#cite_note-26">[26]</a></sup></td>
</tr>
```

There're **6** pairs of `td` tags

Comment: I changed it to 'tr' and am having the same issue. Apparently, 'len(cells) == 7' is incorrect. Would Python recognize (rows, columns) or should I put the number of actual table cells? I was under the impression that the length of the cells was the number of columns. Thank you.

Comment: @SarahMcNamara It is 6 other than 7. you can print row and see it.

Comment: Thank you. If I use 6 instead of 7 I get an error that data will be missing. I tried using 11 since there were 11 rows and 77 since there are 77 total cells and I am still getting an empty .csv file. I still cannot see what is wrong with my code.

Comment: you can print the the rows and check its length